# Is there a way to use nlmeans_opencl filter with a 10 bits source?

Tags: ffmpeg

So far I have only managed to run `nlmeans_opencl` filter with the following settings:

```
ffmpeg -init_hw_device opencl=gpu:0.0 -filter_hw_device gpu -i 10bit_input.ts \
       -vf "hwupload,nlmeans_opencl,hwdownload,format=yuv420p" -an output.mp4
```

Pretty much every other pixel format I set to `format=` fails one way or another. For example

My source is `yuv420p10le`, so that is my first choice, but I get this error:

```
[hwdownload @ 0x55ab32e60c40] Invalid output format yuv420p10le for hwframe download
[Parsed_hwdownload_2 @ 0x55ab32e61c80] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_hwdownload_2
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

With `yuv420p16le`:

```
[Parsed_nlmeans_opencl_1 @ 0x563d97d93600] input format yuv420p16le not supported
Error while filtering: Invalid argument
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

With no `format=...` at all:

```
[hwdownload @ 0x5610a4653380] Invalid output format gray for hwframe download.
[Parsed_hwdownload_2 @ 0x5610a472a400] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_hwdownload_2
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

So, is there any way to make this work, without dropping component precision to 8 bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `nlmeans_opencl` filter supports `yuv420p`, `yuv444p` and `gbrp`, all 8-bit planar formats.